# What travel sites release their API? I am having a hard time searching

Tags: api, e-commerce

I am looking for an API that would give details on everything hotel-related but am having a tough time searching for it.  I was led to believe that expedia or hotels.com opened theres up, but I cannot find it anywhere -

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kayak API: The search API is an HTTP interface that lets you, the programmer, integrate kayak.com searches and results into your web site, desktop application, or mobile phone application. Below is the mashup Kayak Buzz that answers the question: “Where can I go for under a certain amount of money?” It displays airfares under a user defined amount of money on a Google map. http://www.programmableweb.com/api/kayak

TourCMS http://www.tourcms.com/support/api/mp/examples.php, which has lots of users examples about how to use the api.

FlightAware API: Using the FlightXML API, programs can query the FlightAware live flight information and historical datasets. Queries for in-flight aircraft return a set of matching aircraft based on a combination of location, flight or tail number, origin and/or destination airport, aircraft type, and/or a low-to-high range of altitude and/or ground speed, among others. For each matching aircraft, data returned includes the flight or tail number, the aircraft type, origin and destination, time the last position was received, and the longitude, latitude, groundspeed, and altitude of that position. Matching flights’ flight tracks can be requested as well. For airports, FlightXML queries can return a list of scheduled flights, flights that have departed, flights that are enroute to the airport, and flights that have arrived at the airport. http://www.programmableweb.com/api/flightaware

Comment: -1. The Kayak API is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

ProgrammableWeb has a nice list:

http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Travel

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Expedia travel api here: http://www.mashery.com/customers/expedia-affiliate-network